# How to remove .deb package? illegal package name in specifier : character '~' not allowed

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to remove

```
libnvidia-compute-440_440.36-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb

root@miki:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg --remove libnvidia-compute-440_440.36-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

It does not work

```
dpkg: error: --remove needs a valid package name but 'libnvidia-compute-440_440.36-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb' is not: illegal package name in specifier 'libnvidia-compute-440_440.36-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1_amd64.deb': character '~' not allowed (only letters, digits and characters '-+._')
```

What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling without specifying the `.deb` extension— IIRC you're only need to pass the package name.

```
sudo dpkg --remove libnvidia-compute-440
```

I think you can do that with `apt` as well.

```
sudo apt-get remove libnvidia-compute-440
```